# How to update matrix value in R based on comparison of two matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

How to generate a matrix based on a comparison of two matrices. I have (column,row) matrix A (10,1) and B (10, 100). Matrix A is compared to each row of matrix B if the value of B is smaller than A then value B is updated to a value of A.

```
 n.units<-100
 n.option<-10
 A<-rnorm(n.option,1,0.2)
 B<-matrix(rnorm(n.option*n.units,1,0.2)n.col=n.units)
 renew <-function(){Thresholds=obj.value }
 update1 <- apply((Thresholds < obj.value),1,renew)
```

I am new to R programming, please give some advice to solve it.

Comment: sorry.. I have just edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are trying can be achieved with `pmax`. Try

```
pmax(B, A)
```

You have a numeric vector `A` which is compared with matrix `B`. 1st element of `A` is compared with first row of `B` and the maximum value is selected. Same goes for all other rows since `pmax` recycles the shorter vector to the longer vector length. Also note that `pmax(B, A)` gives different structure than `pmax(A, B)` although the value is the same.

---

Just to make it easier to understand, consider this example

```
mat <- matrix(1:10, ncol = 5)
mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
#[2,]    2    4    6    8   10

pmax(mat, c(3, 7))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    3    3    5    7    9
#[2,]    7    7    7    8   10
```

Here 1st row is compared with 3 and second row is compared with 7 and maximum value is selected.

Comment: Thank you, I think that is what I need. Thank you so much.